# How to create blocks and cards in Dash apps written in R

Tags: r, plotly-dash

When building plotly-dash apps in python I can use that dash_design_kit package to create blocks and cards. There does not seem to be a dash_design_kit package in R. Is there a way to create blocks and cards in Dash apps written in R?

Comment: Not super familiar. Just looked around and found this https://dashr.plotly.com/

Answer (score 0):

So there is an R package called dashDesignKit, you just need to have a dash enterprise account to access it and then Dash will let you download a tarball with the package.